# Couldn't match expected type ‘t2 Integer’ with actual type ‘Integer’ on getter

Tags: haskell, ghc

So, I have a type called `TotalDeleted` that contains *amount* and *equivalent*.
On stores the value in a Integer form other in a String for printing(also, I could use intercalate).

The following code looks like:

```hs
data TotalDeleted = TotalDeleted {
    amount :: Integer,
    equivalent :: String
} deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)

amount' :: TotalDeleted -> Integer
amount' t = t.amount

amountTxt' :: TotalDeleted -> String
amountTxt' t = t.equivalent
```

When calling the amount' or amountTxt' inside a function call, gives the following type error: `_Couldn't match expected type ‘t2 Integer’ ... with actual type ‘Integer’`

The code that produces this error are:

````hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let mut = TotalDeleted 0 0
    let contents = getDirectoryContents =<< getCurrentDirectory
    result <- contents
        >>= traverse_ recursiveDeleteDirectory (amount' mut) (amountTxt' mut) <---------

    print (amount' mut)

What is this error and how to avoid it?

------------------------------------

Edit.

```hs

recursiveDeleteDirectory ::  Integer -> String -> IO ()
````

Comment: I'm using only the OverloadedStrings language extension.

Comment: I believe there was a proposal for the syntax `t.amount`, but I think it was not (yet) implemented. For now, the record field access syntax is `amount t`.

Comment: @chi The same. .

Comment: `traverse_` accepts two arguments how it seems you have given it more than that. See: [traverse_](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_)

Comment: Also, I would recommend that you should at least add the type signature of the function `recursiveDeleteDirectory` to the question.

Comment: Can you explain *what* your program is supposed to do?

Comment: notice that the syntax `record.field` is not valid unless you use the `OverloadedRecordDot` extension. In other comment you say `OverloadedStrings` is the only extension you have. that being said records create automatic functions for each field in the style you do manually

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem recursively delete node_modules folder from the enter point and exclude de npm/nodejs/globals from this list. It's a script that I write in every language the I'm learning.

Answer (score 4):

You *probably* meant to write something like:

```
traverse_ (recursiveDeleteDirectory (amount' mut) (amountTxt' mut))
```

The extra parentheses make the application of `recursiveDeleteDirectory` into a single argument to `traverse_`; by comparison, your current code passes three arguments to `traverse_`, namely `recDelDir`, `amount' mut`, and `amountTxt' mut`. My proposed fix assumes `recursiveDeleteDirectory` has the type `Integer -> String -> IO X` for some type `X` (most likely `()`).

If that is indeed the type of `recursiveDeleteDirectory`, may I propose that you change it to `TotalDeleted -> IO X` instead?

Also: you named your thing `mut`, which makes me think you are hoping to update the number inside it as the traversal happens. That won't be possible -- the data is not mutable, even if you give it a name that suggests it. You should probably look into one of `StateT` or `IORef`, depending on your goals.

Comment: For something called `Total`, `WriterT` may be viable...